# How to tune this `scratch` alias for Bash by using the `PS2` variable?

Tags: bash, prompt

Very often, I need to quickly type some lines of characters (for instance for simplifying a mathematical expression) and then discard the whole stuff. Of course, I generally have several running sessions of my text editor, and I can do it there. I have also been using the following system; I type `echo "` in a terminal (running bash) and then type anything; when I am done, I type a closing `"`.

Yesterday, I decided to add something more elegant in my `.bashrc` and I created the following alias:

```
# write junk on the terminal (stop with a line containing only "." )
# alias scratch="awk '/^\.$/{exit}'"
# alias scratch="sed -ne '/^\.$/q'"
alias scratch='grep -q "^\.$"'
```

You can see above three variants doing the same thing: I type `scratch`, then type whatever I want to type, and I end with a line containing only `.` (dot).

I am very happy with that, but I also thought at the following variant:

```
alias scratch="cat - > /dev/null << ."
```

which does the same thing with an initial prompt `>` at the beginning of each line.

Then, I wondered how I could use the `PS2` environment variable for changing this prompt, and I couldn't get anything fully working. Of course, the current `PS2` prompt should be restored when I am done. **How can I set the prompt for this variant of my `scratch` alias to any arbitrary string during the time of the "scratch" session only?**

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I use something like `cat > /dev/null` all the time; you could `alias scratch='cat > /dev/null'` and end with a Control-D or Control-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what this is useful for (compared to `nano`, `vim` or any editor you fancy), but... does it need an alias?

```
$ <<.
> foo
> bar
> baz
> .
```

Just `"` would be even shorter but there'll be an error message...

```
$ "
> oh
> ah
> ui
> "
bash: $'\noh\nah\nui\n': command not found
```

Note that these things are not really gone...

```
$ history
  497  <<.
foo
bar
baz
.
```

If that bothers you, disable history first or clear it afterwards.

For a custom PS2 prompt, it's difficult since (at least for Bash) it has to be set to the parent shell. If you set it in a subshell, it'll be ignored. You can kind of work around it by starting an explicit shell instance like this...

```
$ PS1=@_ PS2=:_ bash --norc
@_<<.
:_hey
:_.
@_exit
$
```

But at this point it would make more sense to write a dedicated scratch and discard program.

Different approach, not using the PS2 prompt at all:

```
$ while read -p ":-> " ; do : ; done
:-> hey
:-> how 
:-> do
```

Only you can't use '.' to get out here. Well, you could easily add that as a condition...

```
$ alias scratch='(var=_; while read -r -p ":-> " var; do [ "$var" == . ] && break; done)'
$ scratch
:-> a
:-> b
:-> c
:-> .
```

However, you can also just get out by sending EOF with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for the `<<.` idea; it is even shorter to type than my current alias!

Answer (score 1):

Use `read` to read input line by line. You can specify a prompt. The following snippet reads lines and ignores their content until a line consisting of optional whitespace around a single dot, or until you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on a blank line.

```
scratch () {
  local line
  while [[ "$line" != "." ]] && read -r -e -p "scratch> " line; do :; done
}
```